# Why are hotkeys not working when using DataTemplate for dynamic menu?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I'm able to bind a collection of my own type to a menu. But I'm struggling with the hotkeys. Either the hotkeys show up but don't work or the hotkeys don't show up but work.

Do you have any idea what goes wrong here?

Here is the stripped-down code:

```
    public class Category : DependencyObject
{
    public string Caption
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CaptionProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Caption", typeof(string), typeof(Category), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ObservableCollection<Item> SubItems
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Item>)GetValue(SubItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SubItemsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SubItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SubItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<Item>), typeof(Category), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
public class Item : DependencyObject
{
    public string Header
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(string), typeof(Item), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
public class MenuViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<Category> MenuCategories
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Category>)GetValue(MenuCategoriesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MenuCategoriesProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuCategoriesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MenuCategories", typeof(ObservableCollection<Category>), typeof(MenuViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MenuViewModel()
    {
        MenuCategories = new ObservableCollection<Category>()
        {
            new Category() {Caption = "_One", SubItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>() { new Item() { Header = "_one"}, new Item() { Header = "t_wo" }, new Item() { Header = "_three" } } },
            new Category() {Caption = "_Two", SubItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>() { new Item() { Header = "_one"}, new Item() { Header = "t_wo" }, new Item() { Header = "_three" } } },
        };
    }
}
public partial class Test1Window : Window
{
    public Test1Window()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MenuViewModel();
    }
}
public class MenuItemContainerTemplateSelector : ItemContainerTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, ItemsControl parentItemsControl)
    {
        var key = new DataTemplateKey(item.GetType());
        return (DataTemplate)parentItemsControl.FindResource(key);
    }
}
```

And the xaml 1. try:

```
<Window x:Class="DynamicMenuTest.Test1Window"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DynamicMenuTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Test1Window" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>

    <local:MenuItemContainerTemplateSelector x:Key="MenuItemContainerTemplateSelector"/>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}">
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Header}">
            <MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <AccessText VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
        </MenuItem>
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Category}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
        <MenuItem VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <!-- Hotkey works but doesn't show up -->
            <MenuItem.Header>
                <AccessText Text="{Binding Caption}"/>
            </MenuItem.Header>
        </MenuItem>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuCategories}"
        UsesItemContainerTemplate ="true"
        ItemContainerTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MenuItemContainerTemplateSelector}"
    />
</Grid>
```

Xaml 2. try:

```
<Window x:Class="DynamicMenuTest.Test2Window"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DynamicMenuTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Test2Window" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>

    <local:MenuItemContainerTemplateSelector x:Key="MenuItemContainerTemplateSelector"/>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}">
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Header}">
            <MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <AccessText VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
        </MenuItem>
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:Category}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
        <MenuItem 
            Header="{Binding Caption}"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center">

            <!-- Hotkey shows up but menu not working -->
            <MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" Content="{Binding }" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
        </MenuItem>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuCategories}"
        UsesItemContainerTemplate ="true"
        ItemContainerTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MenuItemContainerTemplateSelector}"
    />
</Grid>
```

Xaml 3. try:

```
<Window x:Class="DynamicMenuTest.Test3Window"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DynamicMenuTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Test3Window" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>

    <local:MenuItemContainerTemplateSelector x:Key="MenuItemContainerTemplateSelector"/>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}">
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Header}">
            <MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <AccessText VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
        </MenuItem>
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:Category}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
        <MenuItem 
            Header="{Binding Caption}"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <!-- Hotkey shows up but menu doesn't work -->
            <MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <AccessText Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
        </MenuItem>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuCategories}"
        UsesItemContainerTemplate ="true"
        ItemContainerTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MenuItemContainerTemplateSelector}"
    />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Don't use `MenuItem` nested in the data templates. Instead use a `<Style TargetType="MenuItem">` to set the container properties and only write the header contents inside the data template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DataTemplate` and `HierarchicalDataTemplate` describe how the header content of your `MenuItem` should look like, so nesting another `MenuItem` there is a bad idea. Instead, keep it really simple and enjoy:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}">
        <AccessText VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Header}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Category}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
        <AccessText Text="{Binding Caption}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works in my sample. I will now need some time to integrate this into my real project. We will see if it works there also...

Comment: It doesn't work in my real project, because in the DataTemplate I have no option to bind a command which resides in my Item class.

Comment: @MTR Use the `ItemContainerStyle` in order to bind your commands to the `MenuItem`.

Comment: @MTR if you still need help on the command part, update your question example with a command binding and notify me... then I can update the answer.

Comment: How can I set the ItemContainerStyle from my DataTemplate?

Comment: @MTR you can't... you set it from the parent container (the `Menu` and the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` instead. The `DataTemplate` is something *inside* the menu item, so it's not designed to manipulate its surroundings.